# I'm having trouble parsing response from $.ajax

Tags: json, jquery

I'm trying to modify some old code of mine to include comments for photos.  The photos are acquired using $.ajax and the response is in html.

My modification is to get the comments as a json object and then parse the previously attained html inserting the comments where appropriate. Here is the [latest incarnation] of my code (I've tried many different alternatives)

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
        data:"ajax_loadbigthumbs=true&section=<?php echo $_GET['section']; ?>",
        dataType : "html",
        success: function(html){

            jhtml = $(html);

            $.getJSON( "/commentsjson.php?getcomments=true&section=<?php echo $_GET['section']; ?>", function( data ) {

                $.each(data,function(i,item){

                    //alert(item.comment);   <--- this works so I know the data is coming back correctly

                    console.log(jhtml.find('#comments_' + item.photoid).attr("id"));   // this shows 'undefined'

                    jhtml.find('#comments_' + item.photoid).css("display","block").html("<p>" + item.name + " said " + item.comment + "</p>");

                });

                $("#largethumbscontainer").append(jhtml);               
            });


        }
    });
```

But this isn't working.  The console.log line (as a test) returns 'undefined' and the following line  (jhtml.find) has not found anything to modify.

Comment: `alert(item.photoid)` and `alert(jhtml.find('#comments_' + item.photoid).length)`. It is not able to find an element with the said id that is the reason for the error... can you share the value of `html`

Comment: How does html variable look after success?

Comment: I did try alert(item.photoid) and it did return the photo ID.  I'll try the other.

Comment: Just a quick note, never do this: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` without sanitising, as PHP_SELF can potentially be tampered with :), instead do this `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>`

Comment: Noted.  Thanks.  I'll change it.

Comment: html variable is large, so here is a relevant sample of it - "<div style="display:none;"  id="comments_63" ></div>"  In other words I know the html response contains something that should be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, buy appending the html to an already existing element, and then appending the comments to that element....

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php 
        echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); 
    ?>",
    data:"ajax_loadbigthumbs=true&section=<?php echo $_GET['section']; ?>",
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(html){

        jhtml = $(html);
        $("#largethumbscontainer").append(jhtml);
        largethumbs = $("#largethumbscontainer");

        $.getJSON( "/commentsjson.php?getcomments=true&section=<?php 
            echo $_GET['section']; 
        ?>", function( data ) {

            $.each(data,function(i,item){

                largethumbs
                    .find('#comments_' + item.photoid)
                    .css('display','block')
                    .append('<p>' + 
                        item.name + 
                        ' said: <span style="font-style:italic;">' + 
                        item.comment + 
                        '</span></p>');

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $comment = $('#comments_' + item.photoid, jhtml);
if ($comment.length) 
    $comment.css("display","block").html("<p>" + item.name + " said " + item.comment + "</p>");
```

Comment: Can You tell what is in console log if you write:
console.log($comment.length);

Comment: Just a bunch of zeros. :(